# martingale and stochastic Integral

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales, stochastic-integrals

Let ${W_t}$ be 1 dimension Brownian motion and
$X_t:=\exp(t/2)\cos W_t$ $t\in[0,T]$.

Show that $X_t$ is martingale.

I understood $df(t,W_t)=-\exp(t/2)\sin xdW_t$
, but I don't know why it become $X_t=1-\int_0^t \sin X_sdW_s$.

$f(0,X_0)=e^0 \sin X_0=1$? $X_0=?$

Please tell me.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what is giving you trouble in writing $X_t$ in the form you describe?  It should be a straightforward application of Ito's formula.

Comment: I tried to transform $f(t,x)=exp(t/2)\cos x$ and $\partial_{xx}f=-f$, but I cannot explain $\partial_x f=-exp(t/2)\sin x$. This $\partial_x f$ cannot use.

Comment: Look at Ito's formula again.  What does $\partial_x f$ get multiplied by?

Comment: There are many different ways to state Ito's formula, so it would help if you could edit your question to include the version you know.

Comment: Show $\partial_x,\partial_{xx},\partial_t$ and substitute $df(t.x)= \partial_tf(t.x)dt + \partial_xf(t.x)dW_t +\partial_{xx}f(t,x)dt$ ,right?

Comment: You are missing a factor of $1/2$ on the $\partial_{xx}$ term.  That should make the two $dt$ terms cancel.  You will be left with $X_t = 1- \int_0^t e^{s/2} \sin(X_s)\,dW_s$.  A stochastic integral with respect to a martingale is always a local martingale.  Under what condition is it actually a martingale?

Comment: ∂xf=−exp(t/2)sinx is wrong?

Comment: No, $\partial_x f = -\exp(t/2)\sin x$ is absolutely correct.  I'm having trouble understanding what you think is wrong with this.

Comment: This problem's Ito process is $X_t=1−\int_0^t exp(s/2)\sin X_sdW_s$, right?

Comment: Yes. That is true.

Comment: I understood $df(t,W_t)=-\exp(t/2)\sin xdW_t$
, but I don't know why it become $X_t=1-\int_0^t \sin X_sdW_s$.

$f(0,X_0)=e^0 \sin X_0=1$? $X_0=?$

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement that $\mathrm dX_t=A(t,X_t)\mathrm dW_t$ for some regular function $A$ is a shorthand for the fact that $$X_t=X_0+\int_0^tA(s,X_s)\mathrm dW_s$$ 
for every $t\geqslant0$ (or only locally in $t$, but I have a feeling these restrictions are out of this OP's scope).

Apply this to $A(t,x)=-\mathrm e^{t/2}\sin x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(t,x)$ be the function defined by $f(t,x) = e^{\frac{t}{2}} \cos x$. We observe that $\partial_t f(t,x) = \frac{1}{2} f(t,x)$ and $\partial_x^2 f(t,x) = - f(t,x)$. Hence we see that $$\partial_t f(t,x) = - \frac{1}{2} \partial_x^2 f(t,x).$$ This shows that $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a local martingale. To show that $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a full martingale, we need to show that for all $T >0$, that $$\mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^T \left| \partial_x f(t,x) \right|^2 dt \right) < \infty.$$ To this end, we observe that \begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^T \left| - e^{\frac{t}{2}} \sin x \right|^2 dt \right) &=& \int_0^T \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \exp \left( - \frac{x^2}{2} \right) \exp (t) \sin^2 x dx dt \\
&=& \int_0^T \frac{e^t}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin^2 x \exp \left( - \frac{x^2}{2} \right) dx dt \\
&=& \int_0^T \frac{e^t}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \left( \frac{e^2- 1}{e^2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \right) dt \\
& < & \infty.
\end{eqnarray*} So $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is indeed a martingale.